# Issues seeking location in audio using waveform.js library in multitrack setup

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, wavesurfer.js

I am using wavesurfer.js library to create a multitrack player. (https://wavesurfer-js.org/)

My HTML is pretty straight forward:

```
<div id="player"></div>

<div id="player_controls">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-dark" disabled="disabled" id="btn_play"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-dark" disabled="disabled" id="btn_pause"><i class="fas fa-pause"></i></button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-dark" disabled="disabled" id="btn_stop"><i class="fas fa-stop"></i></button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wavesurfer.js/1.3.7/wavesurfer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mixer.js"></script>
```

Then my mixer.js file is as follows:

```
var audiofiles = ["drums.wav","bass.wav","vocals.wav",];

var buttons = {
    play: document.getElementById("btn_play"),
    pause: document.getElementById("btn_pause"),
    stop: document.getElementById("btn_stop")
};

var spectrum = [];
var ready = [];

for(var i=0; i<audiofiles.length; i++){ready.push('false');}

for(var i=0; i<audiofiles.length; i++){
    spectrum[i] = WaveSurfer.create({
        container: '#player',
        progressColor: "#28a745"
    });
    
    spectrum[i].on('ready', function () {
        ready.pop();
        ready.push = 'true';
        checkAllReady();
    });
    
    spectrum[i].on('seek', function () {
        console.log(i);
        // var currentProgress = spectrum[i].getCurrentTime() / spectrum[i].getDuration();
        // for(var j=0; j<audiofiles.length; j++){
            // spectrum[j].seekTo(currentProgress);
        // }
    });

    spectrum[i].load('separations/'+audiofiles[i]);
}

function checkAllReady(){   if(!ready.includes('false')){buttons.play.disabled = false;}}

buttons.play.addEventListener("click", function(){
    for(var i=0; i<audiofiles.length; i++){spectrum[i].play();}
    buttons.stop.disabled = false;
    buttons.pause.disabled = false;
    buttons.play.disabled = true;
}, false);

buttons.pause.addEventListener("click", function(){
    for(var i=0; i<audiofiles.length; i++){spectrum[i].pause();}
    buttons.pause.disabled = true;
    buttons.play.disabled = false;
}, false);

buttons.stop.addEventListener("click", function(){
    for(var i=0; i<audiofiles.length; i++){spectrum[i].stop();}
    buttons.pause.disabled = true;
    buttons.play.disabled = false;
    buttons.stop.disabled = true;
}, false);
```

My issue then is when I try to seek to a location in the waveform on any one track in this section of code:

```
spectrum[i].on('seek', function () {
    console.log(i);
    // var currentProgress = spectrum[i].getCurrentTime() / spectrum[i].getDuration();
    // for(var j=0; j<audiofiles.length; j++){
        // spectrum[j].seekTo(currentProgress);
    // }
});
```

### Edit 1

The `console.log(i);` gave me a '3' here in the console. Thanks to one answer I changed this to:

```
spectrum[i].on('seek', function (position) {
    for(var j=0; j<audiofiles.length; j++){
        spectrum[j].seekTo(position);
    }
});
```

However, seeking to a position just re-calls the same seek function until I get a `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error. Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: Is it possible to give a jsfiddle or codepen for the same ?

Comment: @abhijat_saxena I didn't include it in a code snippet because it won't run at all without the .wav files

Comment: I have a proposed answer - can you see if that works, I was searching for - http://wavesurfer-js.org/docs/events.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking for the position of the selected spectrum ?
try this - if this works ?

```
spectrum[i].on('seek', function (position) {
     console.log(position)
});
```

generally events also comes with event arguments, so attaching an event argument can give you more insights and control over what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yeah the `console.log()` gives me the correct position, however, when I try to get the other tracks to seek to the same position it just keeps re-firing the event until I get a `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error. Any ideas of how I'd get around this?

Comment: Basically I want to `seekTo()` that position for the rest of the tracks without calling the same function again over and over

Comment: Not very sure about this bit - however to stop event from bubbling up - you can use position.stopPropogation(); (but not quite sure about that)


check this - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_event_stoppropagation

Comment: Thanks again for your input but that doesn't work for me unfortunately.

Comment: try requesting a separate new thread for this call stack size exceeded problem. maybe somebody can help

Comment: figured it out, edited question for future reference and accepted your answer as it got me there eventually

Answer (score -1):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author to move it to the answer space).*

Resolved by:

```
spectrum[i].on('seek', function(position){
    console.log(position);
    for(var j=0; j<audiofiles.length; j++){
        var currentProgress = spectrum[j].getCurrentTime() / spectrum[j].getDuration();
        if(currentProgress!=position){
            spectrum[j].seekTo(position);
        }
    }
});
```